# Call AngularJS controller from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading views and scripts on client side. I am trying to achieve to load and call angularjs controller inside my javascript.

1. Load container view(v1.html), main script (eg. myscript.js) and angular.js
2. myscript.js will load view(v2.html) inside v1.html and angular controller(controller.js)
3. v2.html is as: 
   `<div id="v1_id" ng-app="loadApp"  ng-controller="loadCtrl">
   {{msg}} </div>`.
4. controller.js is as:

```js
angular.module('loadApp', []).controller('loadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.load_msg = function(_msg) {
    $scope.msg = _msg;
  }
});
```

5. Call to controller within myscript.js : `angular.element(document.getElementById('v1_id')).scope().load_msg('Hi')`

And error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load_msg' of undefined`.

Any thought on this, what I am missing here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Most of the time you don't need to use `element.scope()`. Anyway, try to put your `<div>` inside the controller, and not everything at the same level, maybe that's it.

Comment: Agree with floribon, `element.scope` is something you use only for a quick debug session in order to inspect the scope. Using it for something else is a big code-smell.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't wait for angular to have bootstrapped (compiled) your HTML, hence the scope is not available. Use `angular.element(document).ready` before running your javascript.

```js
angular.module('loadApp', []).controller('loadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.load_msg = function(_msg) {
    $scope.msg = _msg;
  }
});

// Wait for angular to be bootstraped
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('v1_id')).scope();
  
  // Since we are outside of angular world, we need to $apply the scope
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.load_msg('Hi');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="v1_id" ng-app="loadApp"  ng-controller="loadCtrl">
  {{msg}}
</div>
```

Comment: I am still getting : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined

Comment: As you can see, it is working on my sample code. Could you update your question with what you are doing now?